# Bootstrap navigation bar search field with combobox ( or any drop down)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using  Bootstrap v2.0.2 . Below is the navigation bar I am building for my website

[image]
The search consists of three fields

```
1) Combo box or any drop down 
2) search input text field 
3) Search icon ( click-able )
```

.
Here is the fiddle for above screen shot (Please open it in firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/krg78/1/

Is there any way I can make combobox looks like part of text input ( now two looks different fields) and in place of Search2 showing Search icon which can be click-able ( like in facebook) ?

If I use below lines , I am just getting blank field in place of icon .

```
<span class='add-on' style="float: right"> <i class="icon-search"></i> </span>
```

Thank You all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check http://jsfiddle.net/krg78/2/

You can make combobox looks like part of text input by adding position relative to combobox and moving it on into input:

```
.navbar-search select {
  position: relative;
  left: 84px;
}

.navbar-search input {
  padding-left: 84px;
}
```

Comment: with your tip , I also added search icon to it .Thank You . Here is the link  http://jsfiddle.net/krg78/3/