# dropdown value of navbar should display the value and also render above the text

Tags: html, css

I am creating a navigation bar using html and css3. I have a drop down menu called country.  I need the drop down on top of the text message which would be default value of the dropdown. I have shared both current and expected images of the navbar. I need the drop down menu as shown in expected.

Here is the code

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/NGSR-logo.jpg" /> </a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>


                        <li class="dropdown hideli">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="caret"></span><p>Country</p></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">DE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">GB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">FR</a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>



    </header>
```

**Current Navbar**

[image]

**Expected Navbar**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can change the `hideli` element to:

```
<li class="dropdown hideli">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option><a href="#">DE</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">GB</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">FR</a></option>
    </select>
    <p>Country</p>
</li>
```

Comment: It works but I get a message saying element select is not valid inside the anchor tag. Its not a valid html5. How do I fix this

Comment: I've edited my comment. there are few CSS fixes you may need to apply to make it look exactly like the other links though.

Comment: You have removed the main anchor tag however there are anchor tags in the option element which html5 doesnt like

Comment: consider changing your code to something [like in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003108/bootstrap-navigation-bar-search-field-with-combobox-or-any-drop-down).

check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krg78/2/)

Comment: I tried the example. The example shows creating a form element outside the li. I need to display between the li. it should appear as the image shared